# On method called on double, expectations about the argument

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec3

I have created a double, I am executing code that will call it with a method and a huge hash as a argument, I want to verify one key of the argument, and then return a specific hash.

This is what I am doing

```
before :each do
  allow(@my_double).to receive(:do_stuff).and_return({stuff: 42})
end
it "can do stuff" do
  expect(@my_double).to receive(:do_stuff) do  |arg|
    expect(arg).to be_a(Hash)
    expect(arg[:my_arg]).to eq(3)
  end
  TestObject.stuff() # will invoke do_stuff on the double
end
```

What happens is, the first time `do_stuff` is called, it returns `true` which is the result of the `receive` block, but on subsequent calls(tested in pry) it correctly returns `{stuff: 42}` but since the first call is wrong, my method exceptions out when it tries to call`[:stuff]` on the return.

I am trying to let `allow` define the behaviour of the double so I don't want to put the return in the bottom of the `expect`.. but is there any way around it?

Comment: or is there a cleaner way? like `expect(@my_double).to receive(:do_stuff).with(hash(my_arg: 3))`

Comment: Right now adding `{stuff: 42}` to the bottom of my expect block, but I would like a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer is to use an as yet [undocumented argument matcher](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/dbd5533bb7da56e7c644cbf1f179d254691a1caf/lib/rspec/mocks/argument_matchers.rb) `hash_including` much like my first comment

```
expect(@my_double).to receive(:do_stuff).with(hash_including(my_arg: 3))
```

This works nicely.